# vaadin/java- how to develop multiple language versions of a web app

Tags: java, vaadin

I am a beginner at using Vaadin for designing the UI of my java web app.

What I want to know is, how do I develop multi-language versions of my app- I will use Vaadin for the UI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/rapid.i18n.html should get you started.

If the link changes just search for: `vaadin i18n`

Comment: @TantaouiElMehdi - Fixed. Looks like vaadin rearranged their website.